# android: put call phone in background when is answered

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm developing an Android application that have a button to init a call phone when is clicked.

I want to detect when the call phone is answered and automatically put the native phone application in background and show my application again. Meanwhile, the call phone runs in background.

The result has to look like when you click the back button of the smartphone or if you open manually my application while the call phone is in progress. But this should be done automatically without pressing any buttons.

I know that I have call listeners to do something when the state of call is ringing, offhook or idle, but the problem is putting the call application in background from my application.

Sequence:

1. user clicks button in my app to launch native phone application (Android).
2. the phone call starts (call state: ringing).
3. the phone call is off hook (call state: Off-hook).
4. automatically, my application detects it and puts the native phone app in background and puts my application in foreground.

Is it possible and how I can do it?

Comment: Don't think you can. Once the caller is started it takes over and you can't control that itself.

Comment: Yes, it's what I think too. But maybe there is some way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a background service and implement BroadcastReceivers to listen the call state triggers.

Comment: I already did this, and I could listen the call state but the problem was put my application in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

you can put your app in the foreground after the call was answered using Activity start.

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

now the problem is that the started activity will be a NEW activity (It will clear all previous activites - without these flags it won't return back from the call screen).
i don't know how can I actually return to already working activity in the background.